# Creating a classic menu bar in TraitsUI

Tags: python, mayavi, traitsui

All of the tutorials I have encountered thus far focus on the use of TraitsUI widgets. I would like to find an example of using TraitsUI for an application window with a full-width 'classic' top horizontal menu bar (with a 'File' menu, for 'Open', 'Save', 'Exit' functionality), the rest of the window to be occupied by a Mayavi scene (most of the remaining space) and a right-aligned VGroup of other simple Bool and Float boxes.

Can someone please point me to an example, or suggest how the above layout might be achieved?